tkinter export Undo Stack
As far as I understood the undo feature in tkinter's Text class is implemented via a stack saving the insertions/deletions. (tkdocs)
How can I export this stack so that I can import it the next time the program is launches? (I'm of course also saving the text inside the text box)
-> The text box undo behaviour should be the same after relaunching the application.
maxUndo = 30
self.__textarea = Text(self.__root, undo=maxUndo != 0, maxundo=maxUndo)


As far as I can tell, no such ability exists, not even in the underlying Tck/Tk layer.  There isn't even a way to tell whether the undo/redo stacks are empty or not.

There is no mechanism in the underlying tcl/tk implementation of the text widget that allows us to examine or change the undo stack. If it's not implemented in the tcl/tk man page, it's not a supported feature.
